# Angular Translate for data coming from REST

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I must translate data from a REST service. The data is in the database, the client want this.

In frontend I have this:

Controller:

```
CreateListService.getCharacteristic().then(function(response){
     vm.createListData = response.data;
});
```

View:

```
<select 
    name="" 
    id="territory"
    class="form-control"
    data-ng-options="item.labelEn for item in vm.createListData.territory track by vm.createListData.territory" 
    ng-model="territory">       
</select>
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "confidentiality":[  
      {  
         "id":200,
         "labelFr":"Publique",
         "labelEn":"Public"
      },
      {  
         "id":201,
         "labelFr":"Restreinte",
         "labelEn":"Restricted"
      }
   ],
   "issuer":[  
      {  
         "id":600,
         "labelFr":"Federal Register - OFAC",
         "labelEn":"Federal Register - OFAC"
      },
      {  
         "id":601,
         "labelFr":"Ofac",
         "labelEn":"Internet Ofac"
      }
   ],
   "scope":[  
      {  
         "id":700,
         "labelFr":"Locale",
         "labelEn":"Local"
      },
      {  
         "id":701,
         "labelFr":"Groupe",
         "labelEn":"Group"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is:
Angular 1.4.9,
Angular translate: 2.11.1

My question is how can I change values in view (based on rest key: labelFr and labelEn) when user change language?

I try like this in view:
item.{{labelLang}} for item in vm.createListData.scope track by vm.createListData.scope

and in controller:
$rootScope.labelLang = "label" + capitalizeFirstLetter($scope.selectedLang);
but the values in not updated.

Thank you for all informations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you already get the translated label, then you just have to output it in view.
You use a wrong syntax in your `data-ng-options`.
Try this

```
item[labelLang] for item in vm.createListData.scope track by vm.createListData.scope
```

Comment: Yes, that was! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try angular-translate for TWO or more language.

[angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

https://daveceddia.com/angular/multilingual-angular-using-two-or-more-languages-in-your-app/

Comment: This I use, but I can't find an example with my situation. They use static data in Front, like: i18n/view_name/en.json and i18n/view_name/fr.json